# Keystroke input does not work for assembly kernel

Tags: assembly, input, kernel, interrupt

On 64-bit Ubuntu, I wrote a bootloader that loads a kernel, which provides an echo program (outputs whatever is inputted):

Bootloader Code:

```
    [BITS 16]
    org 0x7C00
    bootdrive db 0
    start:
            mov [bootdrive], dl
            mov ah, 0
            int 13h

            mov dx, 0
            mov ah, 2
            mov al, 0x10
            mov dl, [bootdrive]
            mov ch, 0
            mov dh, 0
            mov cl, 2
            mov bx, 0
            int 13h
            jmp 0x1000:0000
    times 510-($-$$) db 0
    dw 0xAA55
```

Kernel Code:

```
    [BITS 64]
    call _stdin
    jmp $

    _stdin:
            mov ah, 0
            int 16h
            mov ah, 0eh
            mov bx, 0
            int 10h
            ret
```

int 16h/ah=0 takes input and puts the buffer into al. Then, I attempt to print al through int 10h/al=0eh, but it doesn't go through. I even tried putting

```
    mov al, "!"
```

in between

```
    mov ah, 0eh
```

and

```
    mov bx, 0
```

but it doesn't seem to like the 16h interrupt. I also tried various other stdin commands using int 21h (ah = 8, ah = 1, ah = 0ah), but none of them was able to read a keystroke. I would type a key and press ENTER, but nothing would happen. More confusing was the fact that even the output command within int 21h (ah = 02h) did not print anything. I tried switching the kernel to real mode (32 bits) instead of long mode (64 bits), but int 21h still wouldn't work. To be clear, I want to be able to read keyboard input WITHOUT waiting for a return keystroke, so that I can alternate between calling the input interrupt and doing other processes. int 21h did not seem to work, not even in 32 bit mode, as well as int 16. The only interrupts that I have ever actually gotten to work were int 10h and int 13h (shown in the code), but the other interrupts don't work for some reason.

NOTE:
I assembled the bootloader and kernel using nasm bootloader.asm -p kernel.asm to create a bin file named bootloader, and I used qemu-system-x86_64 to run the assembled bin file.

Comment: After a *quick* glance, there are a few things that confuse me: A) there is the `bootdrive` variable in the execution path B) I can't see to find where `es` is set before the call to `int 13h/ah=02h` C) The kernel is assembled with 64-bit default operand size but you don't seem to switch to 64-bit mode D) You never "reset" the video mode, though this is not the issue here, I always felt safer doing it.

Comment: Oh huh, I never knew how to set it to long mode, apparently. Thought it was just [BITS 64] and that was it

Comment: I would have an error show up whenever I set es to anything, by the way, so I just stopped using es. About "bootdrive", I found this other post on stackoverflow about how to get a bootloader to load a kernel, and they saved the value of dl before setting ah to 0 and calling int 13h, so I just followed that

Comment: `bits 64` only tells the assembler to generate 64-bit instruction encodings. It is up to the programmer to place the CPU in long mode before executing 64-bit code. Once in 64-bit protected mode you can't directly access the BIOS functions anymore either (without switching back to real mode first)

Comment: Margaret is pointing out that `bootdrive db 0` will be executed as an instruction potentially causing issue. Place your variables after the last instruction of your bootloader and before `times 510-($-$$) db 0`. `bootdrive db 0` should be placed after `jmp 0x1000:0000` and before `times 510-($-$$) db 0` in your case

Comment: `int 21h` is not available in a bootloader. `int 21h` is a DOS interrupt. DOS isn't available at the stage a bootloader starts, just the BIOS and direct hardware access.

Comment: do the BIOS and direct hardware access have keyboard input interrupts, or do I need to do something to allow DOS interrupts to work

Comment: It goes through when I set the kernel to 16 bits, but the keyboard input still doesn't go through. It stays at whatever al was before the interrupt was called

Comment: only the mrb is loaded to ram, you have to load the kernel code at 0x1000:0x0000 first. then you are still in real mode. `jmp $` jumps to the `jmp` again, so this will only echo one character. the echo-code itself seems ok.

Comment: wait the thought just crossed my mind, do i have to write a keyboard driver for this?

Comment: To have DOS interrupts you need to run DOS. If you are writing your own OS you won't have `int 21h` available. BIOS Interrupts like `int 10h`, `int 13h` etc. are available at boot time. Likely your kernel isn't being run because as Margaret pointed out, you need to use ES:BX to tell BIOS int 13h/ah=2 to read the sectors into memory. Since you seem to be putting the kernel at 0x1000:0000 you'd need to set ES to 0x1000 and BX to 0x0000 before the `int 13h`. You currently set BX to 0 and never set ES

Comment: Ralph Brown's interrupt list is the bible for BIOS interrupts. http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm

Comment: If you were in 32-bit protected mode (or 64-bit long mode) you'd probably find yourself writing a driver to access hardware directly since BIOS interrupts aren't available to do the work for you. As long as you are in 16-bit real mode you can use BIOS interrupts to do keyboard processing. I don't think with the code given that your kernel is even getting to the point of running because you load it to the wrong place in memory with the disk read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDITED]

Here is a program that I wrote that contains both the bootloader and the kernel, that works when converted to a .iso file:

```
    [BITS 16]
    org 0x7C00

    mov ax, 0
    mov es, ax
    mov ah, 2
    mov al, 1
    mov ch, 0
    mov dh, 0
    mov cl, 2
    mov bx, _stage2
    int 0x13
    jmp _stage2
    times 510-($-$$) db 0
    dw 0xAA55

    _stage2:
            call _stdin
            call _stdout
            jmp _stage2
    _stdin:
            mov ah, 1
            mov al, 0
            int 16h
            cmp al, 0
            je _stdin
            mov ah, 0
            int 16h
            ret
    _stdout:
            mov ah, 0eh
            mov bx, 0
            int 10h
            ret
```

Comment: I wonder though how I could make it so that it doesn't wait for you to type something, because this was one of the main things I wanted

Comment: We told you in the comments that ES:BX needed to be set.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by not waiting for you to type something. If you mean check the keyboard buffer to see if a character is present without blocking - you might consider [Int 16/Ah=1 - KEYBOARD - CHECK FOR KEYSTROKE](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1755.htm) If a key is present in the buffer you can then call Int 16/ah=0 to remove it from the buffer and process it.

Comment: It works! I needed this so that I could alternate between checking for a keystroke and doing other processes, kind of like poor man's multithreading

Comment: [`int 16h/ah=0`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1754.htm) doesn't use _ES_.. setting it to 0 isn't going to do anything. Your fix makes no sense. ES is needed for Int 13h/AH=2 to read from disk to memory properly.

Comment: I realized your problem is in how you build your bootloader and kernel. This isn't doing what you think it is doing `nasm bootloader.asm -p kernel.asm`. None of the code in bootloader.asm is actually running as the code in kernel.asm is placed first

Comment: oh, that explains why you guys were saying I was jumping to the wrong address and yet the thing worked anyway. how would I build the 2 files? I have a version of it where I use only 1 file by the way, and I load a jump address for stage 2 on that file. should I use this?

Comment: ??? removed the set es to 0 and it still works! That did NOT work before now. Trying to find the difference between my current code and my earlier code when I posted this.

Comment: You know what, it just so happened to be the kernel code that didn't work without a set es to 0. I tried it in the other version where I only use 1 file for everything, and it works fine. So the thing you said about me not building the bootloader/kernel correctly is likely the main issue.

Comment: Are you building this kernel on Linux,MacOS or Windows?

Comment: Doing this on 64-bit Ubuntu, latest version.

Comment: Normally you'd build each file individually and build a disk image with it. `nasm bootloader.asm -o bootloader.bin` `nasm kernel.asm -o kernel.bin` `dd if=/dev/zero of=disk.img bs=1024 count=1440` `dd if=bootloader.bin of=disk.img conv=notrunc` `dd if=kernel.bin of=disk.img conv=notrunc seek=1` That should create a 1.44MB floppy disk image with your bootloader followed by the kernel. You then boot `boot.img` with your emulator/VM

Comment: Got an error with qemu that it tried to execute code outside disk.img. may have to do with the jmp 0x1000:0000 command. I may just stick to the file that had both the bootloader and the kernel inside it, but I don't know if I am missing out on something by doing that.

Comment: yeah, the file that has both the bootloader and kernel inside it works when converted to a floppy disk, but not the separate files bootloader.asm and kernel.asm

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is for the original reasons expressed. When you split them out and actually put the bootloader before the kernel your bootlaoder code uses int 13h/ah=2 to read the next sector with the kernel in it. The problem is that your code doesn't properly set ES:BX for reading the sectors into memory at the right location, so when you jump to the kernel you end up executing code in a region of memory that never had the kernel read into it.You need to make sure ES is 0x1000 and BX is 0x0000 for the disk read so that the `jmp 0x1000:0000` will jump to the beginning of the kernel

Comment: You also have to make the fix regarding the bootdrive variable as mentioned in the comments under the question.

Comment: when I do mov es, 0x1000, I get error: invalid combination of opcode and operands from nasm. In fact, I get that error whenever I move anything into es, even 0 if i move it directly into es.

Comment: hmm... moved 0x1000 into ax and then moved ax into es and it assembled properly. I wonder why I can't move into es directly. Then, when I did that and put both files into an iso file, and ran it on qemu, it gave an error. Feeling pretty tempted to use that 1 file that contained both the bootloader and the kernel, because that one worked.

Comment: Because you can't move a constant(immediate value) to a segment register directly as it is a limitation of the CPU architecture. You have to move 0x1000 to a temporary register and then that temporary register to _ES_. Same for DS,FS,GS,SS. You could just do `mov bx, 0x1000` `mov es, bx` and then zero bx with `xor bx, bx` .XOR a register with itself zeroes the register. It is preferred over `mov bx, 0` (but both will zero the register)

Comment: By the way, for the 1 file that contained both the bootloader and the kernel, the code for the bootloader part of it was `mov ah, 0x02` `mov al, 1` `mov dl, 0x80` `mov ch, 0` `mov dh, 0` `mov cl, 2` `mov bx, _stage2` `int 0x13` `jmp _stage2` `times 510-($-$$) db 0` `dw 0xAA55` and then I just had a jump point named _stage2: right after. This worked, but it's in 1 file. Are there any limitations with it all being in 1 file and not 2 separate files named bootloader.asm and kernel.asm? If not, I may post the code as a potential answer.

Comment: You can do it that was as well. Although you shouldn't set _DL_ to 0x80. That's the first hard drive. SHould just use the value of _DL_ that is set just before control is transferred to your bootloader. The BIOS will palce the boot drive number in _DL_ for you. If you hard code 0x80 then you won't be able to boot off anything other than what appears to be the first hard drive. In that code that does the one file you should be setting _ES_ to zero. Not setting it It may work on emulators but not usually real hardware.

Comment: alright, edited the answer. anything wrong with it i will change.